# Using a photographic image as a projected light source

Tags: materials, lighting

I'm trying to recreate the light of a movie from a super 8mm projector hitting a cube, so the light stretches over the top and falls off completely at the sides. I've tried using an image as an emitter there is no way of focusing it. I can also see no way of adding an image to a light source in blender.
What's the best way to get started with this?

Comment: You can use a plane with an emmision shader and shape it in a way that focuses the light in the way you want